# Reagarding Split Payments

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, braintree

We would like to integrate payment gateway for Split Payments  . I am considering Split_A,Split_B, Split_C are the three types of vendors . Money would split among them  and credited to their accounts .

Scenario 1:  End user from mobile app purchase something lets say of $100 . Now this $100 should be split and credited to Split_A,Split_B, Split_C  vendor accounts .

Scenario 2:    Split_A  have to have some prepaid amount  , Lets say $1000 . End of the day  (daily)  some amount say $100 would automatically credited to Split_B and Split_C vendors .

We would like to integrate both the  Scenario's  . Please let me know which payment gateway would be feasible to go with . Your inputs required .

Comment: You want to read: https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-a-charge-s-funds-be-split-among-different-connected-accounts which explains that you can't. You need the charge the customer 3 times, once for each vendor instead.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Regarding Scenario 1:

Currently there is no way to charge money to multiple merchants with only one transaction using the Braintree API.

If you want to send payment to multiple merchants in Marketplace and do not mind having multiple transactions recorded, you can call [`Transaction.sale`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/ruby) multiple times, substituting the `merchant_account_id` for the current merchant account's id.

```
result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
  :merchant_account_id => "provider_sub_merchant_account",
  :amount => "10.00",
  :payment_method_token => "payment_method_token",
  :service_fee_amount => "your_service_fee"
)
```

Regarding Scenario 2:

There is not currently a way to transfer money between merchant accounts in the Braintree API.